# C++ Which Number Doesn't Belong?

Tags: c++

I'm kind of a beginner with programming, but while writing a program of my own, I ran into a roadblock that I can't seem to get around.

Anyway, given a set of numbers like these in an array:

```
4
14
24
27
34
```

You can see how all of the numbers except one have a 4 in the ones place. How would I write a function that can return the number that is different in the ones place, 27 in this case? The numbers would be different every time the program is run, but due to the scenario, 4 of them will always have the same digit in the ones place.  They wouldn't necessarily be in numerical order.

I couldn't seem to find a way to do it mathematically, nor was I able to find anything through search. Any ideas?

Comment: but i also see that all the numbers are 2 digits except one.  does that count?

Comment: well the odd number certainly sticks out for one, then there is the number with one digit....

Comment: Mathematically?  How about modulus?  `24 % 10 = 4`, and `27 % 10 = 7`.   You need to figure out which digit is different though.

Comment: Use modulo operator `%` to find the least significant digit.

Comment: All of them are even except 27.

Comment: this is easy.  just hash them to 0..9 using the least significant digit.  the one that is in a bin on its own is the exception..

Comment: even easier... loop through all of them, if you find 1 that is not equal to another 2, then that is the exception.  run time is 3 or the first one that is the exception, whichever is bigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jerry Coffin's solution is unnecessarily `O(log N)`; it can be improved by using `std::partition` rather than `std::sort`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> n = {4, 14, 27, 24, 34};

    int first = n[0]%10;    
    std::partition(std::next(std::begin(n)), std::end(n),
                   [&](int a) { return first == a%10;});

    std::cout << ((first != n[1]%10) ? n.front() : n.back());
}
```

But that still does way too many comparisons. The problem can be solved with at most `(N+1)/2` comparisons:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int odd_man_out(const std::vector<int> n) {
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i + 2 < n.size(); i += 2) {
      if (n[i]%10 != n[i+1]%10)
        return n[i]%10 != n[i+2]%10 ? i : i + 1;
    }
    if (i + 2 == n.size() && n[i]%10 == n[i-1]%10)
      return i + 1;
    else
      return i;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> n = {4, 14, 27, 24, 34};
    std::cout << n[odd_man_out(n)];
}
```

Comment: ah left for a few hours and you guys came up with all sorts of clever tricks :p  remark that in fact it is provable that you can't do better than (N+1)/2 comparisons.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do the job. Definitely not the most efficient possible, but kind of nice anyway. This one will work for any number of inputs, as long as only one is different from the rest (in the units digit, obviously).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> n = {4, 14, 27, 24, 34};

    std::sort(std::begin(n), std::end(n),
        [](int a, int b) { return a%10 < b%10;});

    std::cout << ((n[0]%10 < n[1]%10) ? n.front() : n.back());
}
```

Edit: I decided to add another. While this still does more comparisons than @Rici's (very nice) solution, it's at least linear (and doesn't rearrange the original data):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> n = {4, 14, 27, 24, 34};

    auto pos = std::adjacent_find(std::begin(n), std::end(n),
        [](int a, int b) { return a%10 != b%10; });

    if (pos != std::begin(n))
        std::cout << pos[1];
    else
        std::cout << n[n[1]%10 != n[2]%10];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Write a program using `%` operator to take the unit place value

```
void check ()
{
    int i, changeIndex =0;
    for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
        {
            if (a[i]%10 == a[k]%10)
            {
                changeIndex++;        
            }
        }
        if (changeIndex != 4)
        {
             break;
        }
        changeIndex = 0;

    }
    cout<<a[i];
}
```

This will work for a count of 5 and if only one of the numbers have a different unit place value

Comment: that just gives you the least significant digit.  he wants: *How would I write a function that can return the number that is different in the ones place*

Comment: sorry i dont see any other easy solution :-(

Comment: here you go buddy: http://liveworkspace.org/code/2aBqCp$4 :p trying to reduce the # of lines... 10 lines! :p

Comment: I will check it for sure. Sorry i am not able to access that link now. Its blocked from here. I will check it later @ home :-)

Comment: i'll paste it... it's totally cryptic now.

Answer (score 2):

here you go... :p

works for any number of inputs... and even detects if they're all the same.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
   int a[] = {4,14,24,34,27,94};
   // assume a has more than 2 elements, otherwise, it makes no sense
   unsigned ri = 0;

   if (a[1]%10 == a[0]%10) {
      for (ri = 2; (ri < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])) && (a[ri]%10 == a[0]%10); ri++);
   } else if (a[2]%10 == a[0]%10)
      ri = 1;

   if (ri < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))
      std::cout << "weird number is a["<< ri <<"] = "<<a[ri] << std::endl;
   else
      std::cout<<"they're all the same" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Notice that the actual work:

```
   if (a[1]%10 == a[0]%10) {
      for (ri = 2; (ri < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])) && (a[ri]%10 == a[0]%10); ri++);
   } else if (a[2]%10 == a[0]%10)
      ri = 1;
```

is only 4 lines long! :p

[check it out on liveworkspace](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2aBqCp%2421)

The run time is max(1,[location of the exception #]), which is O(n) where n is the size of a.

Comment: @Toms, I think it may be possible to put everything into 1 for loop... :p